# Command Line Parser Library: Parse a hex string into UInt32

Tags: c#, parsing, command-line-arguments, command-line-parser

I have a console application that needs to take in arguments.  The app uses the [Command Line Parser Library](http://commandline.codeplex.com/) to parse the arguments.

The application needs to be able to take in hexadecimal arguments, and convert them to unsigned integers.

For example, if this is the Option class

```
public class CommandLineOptions
{
   [Option('l', "crcLocation", Required = false, HelpText = "Address where the CRC will be inserted.  Must be outside of the application image")]
   public UInt32 CrcLocation { get; set; }
}
```

then the app should be able to launch with

```
app.exe -l 0x0000000F
```

thus setting `CrcLocation` to 15

Is there a way to make the Command Line Parser Library convert from hexadecimal string to integer, or does the application need to do that manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the library's source code, it internally uses the method `Convert.ChangeType` to perform the conversion, which unfortunately does not support hexadecimal numbers. See: https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline/blob/master/src/CommandLine/Core/TypeConverter.cs#L66

Your best bet is to expose a string and use `UInt32.TryParse` with the correct NumberStyles flags to perform the conversion yourself.